# как сделать необнуляемый счетчик времени?

Tags: java, android

Здраствуйте! нужно сделать счетчик минут между двумя датами, но что бы он считал их постоянно, а не обнулялся каждые 60мин ??

обнуляемый выкладываю:

```
    public long DiffTime() {
    long diffMinutes = 0;
    String currDate = getCurrentTimeDate();
    String oldDate = Time();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;

    try {
        d1 = format.parse(currDate);
        d2 = format.parse(oldDate);

        long diff = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
       
        diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return diffMinutes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Через функцию не выйдет, при вызове return твоё время автоматически обнулится.
Запихни это всё в какой-то класс по типу `MyCustomTimer`, стартуй в нём таймер через конструктор и бери с него время с помощью геттера - `getCurrentTime`.

Comment: вот щас изменил diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60 на diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) и вроде работает...

Comment: Ну, если работает, тогда славненько:)